# Limit number of accepted client certificates when doing mutual TLS

Tags: azure-web-app-service

How can we limit the number of accepted client certificates when doing mutual TLS with Azure web apps?

I want to be able to control the trusted issuers list sent to the web browser so that list of allowed certificates can be filtered in the browser. This was possible in IIS and with Azure Cloud Service I believe but how can we do it in a web app?

Schannel documentation for this in Windows Server 2012:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786429(v=ws.11)

---

What we basically want to do is set the content of the *certificate_authorities* field in *CertificateRequest* sent by the server to the browser in the TLS handshake as stated in [RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4).

---

I've posted a feature request for this:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/35566390-limit-number-of-accepted-client-certificates-when